# Use return type and parameter type of function as template types

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to figure out the return type and parameter type of a function and use them as template types? Consider the following example:

```
template <typename ret, typename in>
class Bar {
  // Some code
}

int foo(float x) {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  Bar<int, float> b; // Can this be done automatically by inspection of foo at compile time?
}
```

Can I use the function signature of foo to set the template types of Bar?

Comment: `Bar<int, float> b` doesn't mention `foo` in any way. What's the supposed connection? In your ideal world, what would the declaration look like?

Comment: Im not sure if I understood correctly, but I believe you are trying to do the exact opposite as what templates are used for? In that case, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I believe you can use something like this `decltype(foo(1.0))` to get the return type of a function. And then you can use it like this: `Bar<decltype(foo(1.0)), float> b;`

Comment: You can write a type trait and specialize for `R(*)(T)` where `R` and `T` are template arguments.

Comment: @Nadir I get that. Lets assume that foo-code is generated by some other stakeholder and I don't want to touch my code all the time.

Comment: Are you trying to use arbitrary function's return type as first template argument and function's argument type as second template argument?

Comment: there is `std::function` [doing something similar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides). Although I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: I'm vote to close as unclear because the `b` in question does not use `foo` in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yessir.

```
template <class Function>
struct BarFor_;

template <class Ret, class In>
struct BarFor_<Ret(*)(In)> {
    using type = Bar<Ret, In>;
};

template <auto function>
using BarFor = typename BarFor_<decltype(function)>::type;
```

Now you can get your type via:

```
 BarFor<foo> b;
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a442ba5fac7b6309)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can get the return type of function but you cannot get the type of a function argument (at least in a way you are doing it right now).

This is how you can deduce the return type of a function:

```
Bar<decltype(foo(1.0)), float> b;
```

However, you need to pass an argument to the `foo` function which I think is not what you want.